# How to select content from a table into a new table in SQL stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to write a procedure and needed to copy `output_1` table into a new one.

This procedure :

```
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO newtable FROM output_1;
END
```

returns the following error :`Undeclared variable: newtable`

I thought it would create a new table and all its columns automatically.

How do I `SELECT` multiple columns of a table `INTO` a new table using a stored procedure?

### EDIT :

In stored procedures, when you want to use a table to *store* data *temporarily*, you should consider using [`temporary tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html).
Typically, if you try to store a table in a variable, you will get a `multiple rows` error ; in this case, temporary tables can replace variables.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM output_1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select into a table. You possibly intended

```
create table newtable as select * from output_1;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html